# Is there a way to send ids to both actions in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the code below, I'll like to pass @sensors.map(&:id) which are ids to both new and show action by using link_to. However, I tried both of the code below, but it looked like I could only send the ids to one of the actions. Is there a way to send the ids to both of the action?

Working Code

```
<%= link_to 'Function Chart', new_function_chart_path(sensors_ids: @sensors.map(&:id)) %>
```

Does Not Work

```
<%= link_to 'Function Chart', new_function_chart_path(sensors_ids: @sensors.map(&:id)), function_chart_path(sensors_ids: @sensors.map(&:id)) %>
```

Comment: No, but if you want to do two things from one button click, create another action pass collection of ids there and do two things inside controller action.

Comment: @Fabio Hello, how would you do that? Thank you

Comment: _create another controller action, pass collection of ids to that action and execute code from other two actions in this one_

Comment: A link can't go to two places. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Classic X&Y question. As @TomLord already has pointed out a link can't go to to two places. So why don't you describe what you are actually trying to build instead of what you think the solution is.

Answer (score 2):

I think what @Fabio is saying can be show in pseudo code like this

```rb
class SomeController
  def main_action_which_need_to_be_called_with_id(ids)
    # do some stuff in here and 
    # call 
    second_action_which_need_to_be_called_with_id(ids)
  end

  def second_action_which_need_to_be_called_with_id(ids)
    # do other stuff for second method
  end
end
```

And when you do something like this

```rb
<%= link_to 'Function Chart', main_action_which_need_to_be_called_with_id(sensors_ids: @sensors.map(&:id)) %>
```

Both of your action will be executed.

I hope this 'code' is understandable, if not leave a comment, I will try to clarify.