# Is there a way to send the same information to two different actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have search controller that searches for sensors. If a user searches for the specific attributes, they get a list of sensor that matches the searched attributes and the amount of searched sensors are stored in a variable called `@sensors`.

In the search show page, there is a `<%= link_to "Analyze Results", charts_path(sensors_ids: @sensors.map(&:id)) %>` which allows `@sensors` to be sent over to the chart controller index action.

In the chart index view page, there is a link, which if clicked goes to the function chart to make a graph from the data from the sensors. The problem is that I need the data from the sensors to go to the function show page and not the function new page. However, I cannot send ids to two different action, so is there a way to do it?

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <%= link_to 'Function Chart', new_function_chart_path(sensors_ids: @sensors.map(&:id)) %>
</div>
```

Incorrect version

```
<%= link_to 'Function Chart', new_function_chart_path(sensors_ids: @sensors.map(&:id)), function_chart_path(sensors_ids: @sensors.map(&:id)) %>
```

Comment: What do you mean "I cannot send ids to two different action"? Why are you trying to do this? Why are you passing two paths in your "incorrect version"?

Comment: You asked a [very similar question a few weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58985498/is-there-a-way-to-send-ids-to-both-actions-in-rails), but didn't respond to the comments. And you still haven't really explained what you're trying to do -- What do you mean by *"I need the data from the sensors to go to the function show page and not the function new page."*? It doesn't make any sense to "send the data to one page, but load a different page". A link goes to one page, not two.

Comment: @TomLord first off, thanks for helping. What I'm trying to do, if the user clicks on "Function Chart", I need the user go to the new_function_chart_path, but I need the data from the sensors to go to the function_chart_path.

Comment: @TomLord I don't need the data in the new_function_chart_path, but only in function_chart_path

Comment: @YLim "I need the data from the sensors to go to the function_chart_path" doesn't make sense. Data doesn't "go to a page"; the user does. And the user can't go to two pages, from one link. If you want someone to answer the question, you need to provide more information... What code is in the `FunctionChartController`? What do you want the user to see?

Comment: @TomLord so a lot of controller belongs to sensor such as```class Sensor < ApplicationRecord
 validates :name, presence: true
 belongs_to :publication
 has_one :setup_variable, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy
end```  like this and in the ```setup variable``` there is data such as concentration and the response. I would like to make a graph out of the data.

Comment: I need to somehow grab the concentration and the response in the ```setup variable``` and transfer them to function_chart_path to graph them.

Comment: Can I suggest posting a new question with **all** of this critical information, upfront in the main question? What code is in the controller? What code is in the view? What is "data such as concentration and the response"? What is the code that generates the graph? It sounds to me like what you really need to do is share some common functions in the controller and/or render some common partials in the view. But as it stands, I really cannot give any concrete advice since the information you have provided is vague and ambiguous.